# Have Excel return value based on multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a sheet that essentially acts like a database consisting of three columns: description (`string`), rate (`numeric`), and fee (`numeric`).

I am trying to construct a dynamic search functionality that returns the correct result from the database based on the input of card initials, rate, and fee. (See picture)

[image]

So far, I managed to have it return all aliases that match the rate and have it highlight the cell that contains the given description.

However, I want it to contain a condition that only returns the entries with the correct card initials like "MC" based on cell input in B3:C3. Currently, it returns VS, MC, and DC, rather than only MC. I also want it to return the result that matches the fee. So essentially, it should return the entry from the database that matches Card Initials, the Rate, and the Fee. Presently, it only accounts for the rate.

How can I go about doing this?

Edit: Forgot to mention how I am obtaining the rate and the fee.
I use a vlookup formula:

```
=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(E3,fdata,2,FALSE)), "", VLOOKUP(E3,fdata,2,FALSE))
```

Comment: Can the data base be adjusted such that the initials are in their own column? Same with description?  It makes looking up information much easier, not impossible though.  Will you have multiple entries that match your 4 conditions?  Initials, description, rate and fee?

Comment: some sample text data in your question would be nice to work with.

Comment: We cant see what is in B3, but you are referencing it in your question.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Based on the above layout, assuming that C1 to E10 is the layout of your database/worksheet and you search criteria are in the A12:A19 area, then you can use the following formula and copy it down to meet the anticipated number of entries:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(C$2:C$10,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(C$2:C$10)/(($A$13=LEFT($C$2:$C$10,2))*(ISNUMBER(SEARCH($A$15,$C$2:$C$10)))*($A$17=$D$2:$D$10)*($A$19=$E$2:$E$10))-ROW($C$2)+1,ROW($A1))),"")
```

That formula was then copied to the right to pull the information from adjacent columns Rate and Fee.  In this example I placed the formula in C12 and copied to D12 and E12.

Comment: The database is not in C1 to E10. It is located in another worksheet. Here is what a few rows of it look like: http://screencast.com/t/X80o2nwtAs. Based on input of Rate, Description, and Card Name, the Alias, Rate, and Fee returns values from the database and populates them into columns C, D, and E.

Comment: Regarding your question on what is present in cell B3, it is just the card initial "MC". Cells B3 and C3 were simply merged and centered.

Comment: you should just need to update the cell references to match your needs.